# Call a function of object literal from itself

Tags: javascript, this

I tried execute this code:

```
    var system = new Object();

    (function($) {
        $.init = function() {
            var o = {
                message: function(arg) {
                    return arg.val;
                },
                alert: this.message({
                    val: "Hello, world."
                })
            };
            return o.alert;
        };
    })(system);

    alert(system.init());
```

but, when I execute it I get error message which tells me that this.message is not a function. Obviously, `this` not refers to object `o` itself, and I want to know why.
I found few solutions on stackoverflow where `this` is always inside function body, but why `this` can not be outside? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way in JavaScript to reference an object literal from inside.

Comment: Also, returning just `o.alert` from that "init" function means that the rest of the "o" object is not useful.

Comment: I have seen that plugins of jQuery can set options in this way. Found that solution: options: `$.extend({'animated': true,}, options)`, where extend is function like `alert` in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
var system = new Object();

(function($) {
    $.init = function() {
        var o = {
            message: function(arg) {
                return arg.val;
            }
        };
        o.alert = o.message({
            val: "Hello, world."
        });

        return o.alert;
    };
})(system);
system.init()
```

Yields:

```
"Hello, world."
```

In your code `this` would refer to window in that context. If you want to create an object and refer to it as `this` - use constructor function, i.e.:

```
var o = new function(){
    ...
    <here: this == o>
    ...
}
```

Comment: hm, so I should define `o.alert` after. Why? Is it problem that `this` do not know about object `o`, or what?

Comment: `this` would refer to `window` in that context. If you want to create an object and refer to it as `this` - use constructor function, i.e.: `var o = new function(){...<here: this == o>...}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use an anonymous constructor function instead of object literal syntax if you want to reference the object during instantiation.

```
(function($) {
    $.init = function() {
        // -----vvv---vvv---constructor function
        var o = new function() {
            this.message = function(arg) {
                return arg.val;
            },
            this.alert = this.message({
                val: "Hello, world."
            })
        };
        return o.alert;
    };
})(system);
```

Because the value of `this` is only defined within a function when the function is invoked, object literal syntax never changes its value.

So instead we create a function, and invoke it using `new` so that the value of `this` in the function is a reference to the new object we're building.

And of course it doesn't need to be anonymous, but if you're only going to use it once, there's no need for a name.